# html and php drop down list

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

How to declare multiple variables in php so that it can be accessed in html script.
Ex:: as scenario in html i m creating three drop down list

```
     1.drop down list 1
     2.drop down list 2
     3.drop down list 3
```

if drop down list'1' has 3 options such as

```
1.india
2.uk
3.china
```

and each country has several states , and this has to be displayed in drop down list '2'..
If the user selects india than all the states has to b shown in drop down list'2' or '3'

Comment: Sounds like an Ajax song. JQuery might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to group options in a `select` is using `optgroup`:

```
<select name="country">
  <optgroup label="America">
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This will show all options at once, so it's not good it a "list group" has a lot of options. A better solution will be using the groups in one `select` and load by AJAX the children when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the $.ajax() method from jQuery. I would create a database with all your countries in one table, then in another table list all the states and what country they belong to.

```
Country | pkid

State   | pkid | fk_countryID
```

Then you can write a PHP page that will pull all the states that are from the same country based on data that you pass it with Ajax. The page would echo out each state name, all separated by a pipe("|").

Then you'd create your ajax call based on what the user selects from the country drop-down. You'd want to build your drop-down with the same data that's in the database, so that when they select india for instance, the value of india is the same as it's pkid in the database.

The ajax call will return the pipe delineated set of states that you can then split into an array and throw into another drop-down, all without refreshing the page.